# JS function with timeout supposed to send data every 4 secs, but only sends 1 time

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Through JS I run a function every 4 seconds. This function send some data to the `online` mySQL table using PHP from `handler.php` that is called.

On first load, the row is created. But I thought that a new row should be inserted every 4 secs. Isn't suppose to do this?

Amn I missing something?

```
setTimeout ( "iAmHere()", 5000 );
function iAmHere() {
requestServerCall("http://domain.com/handler.php?type=active&callback=Response&cookie="+ hash +"");
setTimeout ( "iAmHere()", 4000 );
}
```

handler.php

```
if ($_GET["type"] == 'active') {
mysql_query("INSERT into `active` (`hash`) values ('$hash')");
}
```

Update:
the reason I wait for 5 secs to run it for the first time is because I wait for the `hash` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(iAmHere, 5000);

function iAmHere() {
    requestServerCall("http://domain.com/handler.php?type=active&callback=Response&cookie="+ hash +"");
}
```

Edit:

If your not using `iAmHere()` elsewhere you can put them together like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    requestServerCall("http://domain.com/handler.php?type=active&callback=Response&cookie="+ hash +"");
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use nested setTimeout statements, this is what causes the stack size error.  Use the setInterval() method.

```
function foo(){
.....
}
setInterval(foo, 4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setInterval ( iAmHere, 5000 );

Comment: `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: @holtc is the correcy answer.